# Display ACF checkboxes values

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF Pro. I am trying to display the selected checkbox values on Single Product Page. It doesn't display as intended and there are no error messages. I've tried `get_field()` but still to no avail.

#1

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', ' display_food_checkboxes', 6);
function display_food_checkboxes() { 
    $terms = the_field('available_day');
    echo implode($terms, ','); 
  }
```

#2

```
    function display_food_checkboxes() { 
    $terms = get_field('available_day');
    if ( $terms) {
      foreach ( $terms as $term) {
        echo '<p>' . $term . '</p>';
      }
    }
     add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', ' display_food_checkboxes', 6);
```

Comment: the_field already echoes, so doing echo implode of that is likely an issue

Comment: It could also be that you are outside the loop, can you try $terms = get_field('available_day', get_queried_object_id() ); ?

Comment: you need to provide the post id to get_field.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Fixed this by adding `global $product;`